# SVN: Keep Folder; Ignore Content

Tags: svn, build, svnignore

Folks,

How can I permanently ignore the content of a folder with SVN? I have a "build" folder, but as I add new source libraries, etc., new content gets created, the I have to manually go and add to ignore list.
In git is easy to do, but I can't find a way to automate it on SVN

Comment: It's not clear from your post whether you want to ignore all the files in the folder or only a subset of files in the folder.

Comment: I want to ignore the folders content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`svn:ignore`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) property to ignore the build folder entirely.  Execute this command in the same folder that the "build" folder is in:

```
svn propset svn:ignore build .
```

Then commit the change.